# angular route params not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

i need to passe id using $routeParam. my code is like below

js file

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp");

app.controller("quotationPendingController", function ($scope,$http,NgTableParams,$filter,$timeout,$rootScope,ModalService,$window){

$scope.loadQuotationDetailsOnQuotationForUpdate =  function (quotation) {

$window.location.href = ('quotation_approve.jsp#/?target='+quotation.quotationId+'&action=u');
}

});
```

```html
jsp file like below 

> Blockquote

<a class="grid-btn row-edit" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit"  ng-click="loadQuotationDetailsOnQuotationForUpdate(quotation)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

i need to change loadQuotationDetailsOnQuotationForUpdate(quotation) function from $routeParam.

how i change below function

```js
$scope.loadQuotationDetailsOnQuotationForUpdate =  function (quotation) {

$window.location.href = ('quotation_approve.jsp#/?target='+quotation.quotationId+'&action=u');
}
```

Comment: What does your routing look like? Why are you calling $window vs using $location? I think having a demo would help here.

Comment: when i click the link page is loading. but there no styles and script files.

Comment: Dear Brian.. can u do small example for me if not u busy

Comment: however i need to change loadQuotationDetailsOnQuotationForUpdate() function from using $routeParam

Answer (score 1):

In Angular we can advise you to use a true router component to manage your navigation.
For sample with ui-router (https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) something like
 :

1) you can define a specific state for your jsp

```
$stateProvider
 .state('quotation_approve', {
 url: '/quotation_approve.jsp/:target/:action',
 templateUrl: 'quotation_approve.jsp',
 controller : "your template controller"
})
```

2) then you will be abble to change the function to navigagte to your page

Don't forget then inject $state service to your controller

```
$scope.loadQuotationDetailsOnQuotationForUpdate =  function (quotation) {
   $state.go('quotation_approve',{ "target": quotation.quotationId,"action":"u"});
}
```

Comment: hi jeremy... i followed your code. now issue is quotation_approve.jsp not loading.

Comment: do you have an error like 404? could you check the path to get your file ?